# Kapacitor task with multiple percentiles

Tags: influxdb, telegraf, kapacitor

I want to aggregate data from last minute from telegraf with kapacitor before putting them into influxdb and I also have this need for calculating few percentiles. And so I wrote a simple tick for test

```
var firstPerc = stream
    |from()
        .measurement('my_tmp_measurement_from_telegraf')
var secondPerc = stream
    |from()
        .measurement('my_tmp_measurement_from_telegraf')
firstPerc
    |join(secondPerc)
        .as('fp', 'sp')
        |percentile('fp.myAggVal', 50.0)
        |eval(lambda: "percentile")
            .as('50p')
        |percentile('sp.myAggVal', 90.0)
        |eval(lambda: "percentile")
            .as('90p')
        |window()
            .period(60s)
            .every(60s)
            .align()
        |influxDBOut()
            .database('myDBInInflux')
            .retentionPolicy('autogen')
```

In my database, I have only values for 50th percentile, and I am not suprised with that since I use "percentile" in my eval but still, I cannot find in Kapacitor documentation any clue about how to get result I need.

Here you have "visual" result I crave for:

```
time 50p 90p someOtherP's otherDataICanPropablyHandle
```

Halp!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same measurement stream (and the same data in it) twice, so data are popped. First you should save the measurement stream:

```
var myStream = stream
    |from()
        .measurement('my_tmp_measurement_from_telegraf')
```

Next define streams using saved measurement. You should define here proper grouping, evaluations, etc.:

```
var firstPerc = myStream
    |percentile('myAggVal', 50.0)
    |eval(lambda: "percentile")
        .as('percentile')
    |window()
        .period(60s)
        .every(60s)
        .align()
var secondPerc = myStream
    |percentile('myAggVal', 90.0)
    |eval(lambda: "percentile")
        .as('percentile')
    |window()
        .period(60s)
        .every(60s)
        .align()
```

Finaly, it's time to define join stream:

```
var joinedStreams = firstPerc
    |join(secondPerc)
        .as('50', '90')
        .tolerance(1s)
        .streamName('measurementName')
        |influxDBOut()
            .database('myDBInInflux')
            .retentionPolicy('autogen')
            .create()
```

The output:

```
time                50.percentile 90.percentile
```

I strongly suggest using .tolerance(), which will group measurements within the same tolerance period.